# Are the inn prices listed in the rules per room or per person?

Tags: dnd-5e, pricing, lifestyle

The Food, Drink, and Lodging table in the [Expenses](https://dnd5e.info/equipment/expenses/) section of the rulebook lists the prices for a single night's inn stay.

These prices are normally included in the lifestyle expenses, but since I don't currently use those they can also be used separately per need.

However, the rules aren't very clear about whether the prices are per room or per person.

For example, if a group of 4 PCs rents a room at a Comfortable inn, listed at 8 sp per night, does each PC pay 8 sp? Or do they split the price, with each PC paying only 2 sp?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### There aren't rulings, but it's implied that the price is per person

Lifestyle Expenses implies that inn stays at Comfortable and above are private.

> You live in a small cottage in a middle-class neighborhood or in a private room at a fine inn.

You could abstract, from that, that inn fees are calculated on a per-person basis, as everything else on the list. *Banquet* only outlines "per person" because the common usage of banquet is understood as a feast for several people.

Finally, a case could be made against the "per-party" fee by considering the pricing ratio for the inn service split four ways when compared to a single-person food service, making an overnight hotel stay much cheaper than the food served in the hotel, but that's even more implied and assumed than the rest of this already theoretical answer.